# Python Webdriver IE11 Unable to find element on closed window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My Python Webdriver tests were working fine but I have reinstalled IE11 as i installed IE10 to verify some Jira defects.
I have IE11 back on, my tests now fail.  I get the following error:
NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to find element on closed window

Having read other posts from people with similar issues.  I have followed the instructions from: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

I don't have the following value in the reg editor so I have had to skip this part also:
For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE

Also in IE11 Internet Options Advanced under Security I do not have the option Enhanced Protected Mode.
I have hd to skip this part.

To turn off Enhanced Mode if the option does not exist in the browser options I followed the instructions from here:
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/31977-internet-explorer-enhanced-protected-mode-turn-off.html

To Turn Off Enhanced Protected Mode in your IE10 or IE11

A) Click/tap on the Download button below to download the file below, and go to step 4 below.

Turn_Off_EPM_for_IE.reg

download the file (there was a link provided)

4. Save the .reg file to your desktop.
5. Double click/tap on the downloaded .reg file to merge it.
6. Click/tap on Run, Yes (UAC), Yes, and OK when prompted to approve the merge.
7. Restart the PC to apply.

I am still getting the error.

My tests still do not run.  Is there something I am missing?

The code i use to run is as follows:

```
    webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER["unexpectedAlertBehaviour"] = "accept"       
self.driver = webdriver.Ie("C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.46.0\IEDriverServer.exe")
self.driver.get("http://riaz-pc.company.local:8080/clearcore")
self.login_page = login.LoginPage(self.driver)
self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
```

If i try with the following code:

```
    caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
    caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
    self.driver=webdriver.Ie(capabilities=caps)
    self.driver.maximize_window()
```

I get the following error:
 "IEDriver executable needs to be available in the path. "
WebDriverException: Message: IEDriver executable needs to be available in the path. Please download from http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

I have set the environment variable path as follows:
From Control Panel\System\Environment Variables
select and edit  Path from System Variables
I set the value as follows C:\QA\Automation\Python_projects\Selenium Webdriver\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.46.0;

IEDriverServer.exe is in the folder IEDriverServer_Win32_2.46.0

I am running Windows 7
I have set Enable Protected Mode for all the zones from internet options.

Some help appreciated, thanks.